# Link in email for user to update a custom record in Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, email

I have the following requirements which I would like to perform in Salesforce but I am not sure if it is feasible or the effort involved, so any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

- Send email to contacts in Salesforce
- Contact is related to an Account
- Embed a link to visualforce page to allow user to submit a numeric value.
  I am not sure if the VF page is neccessary or if the user can just submit the value by replying to the email. Value is a field on a custom record(custom record is a child record of an Account)
- Email needs to only be valid for a month if possible. User is submitting a value that is only relevant for the current month

Comment: It's do able with force.com sites, but it may not be for the faint of heart. I'd only suggest that if you are willing to put in the time to get it going. If its only a limited number of contacts & values then i'd suggest you do it by hand.

Comment: you could use apex inbound email handler if you just want the user to enter a value in the subject or body of the email; no VF (but then, no form either)

Comment: the value being returned does not need to be in a form.  But will I be able to make sure the value being returned is formatted correctly?  For example I need 200 and the user submits 200.3.  Does the apex inbound email handler have the configuration option to expire the email and to determine if the user has already submitted a value?  Or do I need to perform that validation in Salesforce?  Thanks  M